# wagmi error write() undefined

Tags: walletconnect, wagmi, wagmi-react

Hi all I think I am getting lost with my code. I am using WalletConnect for the modal.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, ActivityIndicator, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { useAccount } from "wagmi";
import {
  usePrepareContractWrite,
  useContractWrite,
  useContractEvent,
} from "wagmi";
import {
  usdtAddress,
  usdtAbi,
  paymentAdress,
  paymentAbi,
} from "../data/constantContracts";

function TesterScreen() {
  const { address } = useAccount();
  const dummyAmmount = 5 * 10 ** 6;

  const dummyTargetAddress = "0x26baAC08CB753303de111e904e19BaF91e6b5E4d";

  // write on custom contract

`  const { config: paymentConfig } = usePrepareContractWrite({
    address: paymentAdress,
    abi: paymentAbi,
    functionName: "makePayment",
    args: [dummyTargetAddress, dummyAmmount],
  });

  const { data: paymentData, write: paymentWrite } =
    useContractWrite(paymentConfig);

  // approve usdt
  const { config: approveConfig } = usePrepareContractWrite({
    address: usdtAddress,
    abi: usdtAbi,
    functionName: "approve",
    args: [paymentAdress, dummyAmmount],
  });

  const {
    data: approveData,
    isLoading,
    isSuccess,
    write: approveWrite,
  } = useContractWrite(approveConfig);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Text>{address}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => approveWrite()}
        style={{ marginVertical: 20, backgroundColor: "#0F9D58" }}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: "white", padding: 5 }}>Approve</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => paymentWrite()}
        style={{ marginVertical: 20, backgroundColor: "#0F9D58" }}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: "white", padding: 5 }}>write Contract</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

export default TesterScreen;`
```

With this code
1.- I approve tokenes
2 .- write to my contract

But somehow second hook is failing:
ERROR  TypeError: paymentWrite is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes

This ONLY HAPPENS when i restart my APP and i call my functions one after another.

Hope someone can help Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, my problem is that usePrepareContractWrite was returning an error:

WARN  [ContractFunctionExecutionError: The contract function "makePayment" reverted with the following reason:
ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance

this was causing write() function to be undefined.

solved using  const { config: paymentConfig, refetch: paymentRefetch } =
usePrepareContractWrite(.....)

and using paymentRefetch() when approve tokenes success.